# How to get internet request information like these by objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

[image]

I want to get some request information（Request Timing\Size like the picture show） when I posted a http/https request.

Is there any sdk or framework can help me to catch these information like the picture show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at AFNetworking : networking framework
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger : this logs details on your requests